# Image rotate to mouse using Jquery and CSS

Tags: jquery, mouse, rotation

I have a compass image and am trying to get the needle to follow the mouse around the page, exactly how the images are rotated in the following demo but without having to shift and click. I'm having trouble breaking down that code however, so any help would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance.

http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/smooth-rotatable-images-css3-jquery/

The images are simply wrapped in a div

```
<div id="content">
<img id="compass" src="compass.png"/>
<img id="needle" src="needle.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: do you know trigonometry, or do we have to teach you how to determine the angle from three obligatory points?

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm sure my secondary school maths will carry me through

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/x2d8pmub/

```
var img = $('.image');
if(img.length > 0){
    var offset = img.offset();
    function mouse(evt){
        var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width()/2);
        var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height()/2);
        var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90; 
        img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    }
    $(document).mousemove(mouse);
}
```

Comment: @ZachSaucier The relevant code is contained within the answer. Nothing else of use was in the link

Answer (score 1):

Rather than type up a long answer about how to do CSS rotations, I'll just link you to [this good writeup](http://joncom.be/code/css-clocks/).

As for figuring out the angle to rotate by, you'll need to know the position of the center of the compass, and the location of the mouse. Bind a `mousemove` event on the document to update the compass when the mouse is moving.

Find the difference in x and y:

```
dx = mouse.x - compass.x;
dy = mouse.y - compass.y;
```

Assuming that rotation goes clockwise, and that 0° is vertical (this will reverse the `Math.atan2` arguments), `tan(Θ) = dx / dy`.

`Θ = arctan( dx / dy );`

or in JS

```
angle = Math.atan2( dx, dy );
```

Let me know if I've messed up the order of subtraction for `dx` & `dy`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function of css3 to rotate the div

```
img {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
}
```

and you can use the method "draggable()" of jQuery UI to move it :)